# Add Background Color to Listview's Specific Row

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
Change the listview's background color to light colored grey if the current time pass the appointment time. For instance, the time is 10.15 and you have background color for the 09.30 - 10.30 and 10.00 - 11.00.

Problem:
I do not know what syntax I need to use in order achieve the goal. I also reviews some advice from different website and their advice is not enough.

Information:
- I'am using Nhibernate to retrive the data.
- This is a usercontrol.

[image]

```
   private void DisplayActivityBasedonSelectedDate()
        {
             DateTime aa = (DateTime) cdate_left.SelectedDate;

             lvw_aktivitet.DataContext = _myNhibernateDataProvider.RetrieveAllActivitetBasedOnDate(aa);

             DisplayDateInTheLabel();
        }


        public IList<Aktivitet_data> RetrieveAllActivitetBasedOnDate(DateTime pDatum)
        {
            return _session.GetNamedQuery("sp_retrieveAllActivitetBasedOnDate").SetDateTime("Datum", pDatum)
                        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Aktivitet_data))).List<Aktivitet_data>();

        }



    public class Aktivitet_data
    {
        public string PK_Aktivitet_schema { get; set; }
        public string Datum { get; set; }
        public string Tid { get; set; }
        public string Aktivitet { get; set; }
        public string Total_platser { get; set; }
        public string Bokade { get; set; }
        public string Drop_in { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="usercontrol_bokning.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="White" Margin="-127,0,-777,-316">
        <ListView x:Name="lvw_aktivitet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="337" Margin="217,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" SelectionChanged="lvw_aktivitet_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Tid" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tid}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Aktivitet" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Aktivitet}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Total platser" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Total_platser}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Bokade" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bokade}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Drop in" Width="auto"  >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Block.TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Drop_in}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Calendar x:Name="cdate_left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDatesChanged="cdate_left_SelectedDatesChanged"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_idag" Content="Idag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn_idag_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="arrow__left" Click="Arrow_left_Click" Background="Transparent">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Image x:Name="bild_arrow_left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="302,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\left.jpg" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="arrow__right" Click="Arrow_right_Click" Background="Transparent" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Image x:Name="bild_arrow_right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="326,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\right.jpg"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_DisplayDateBySelection" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="396,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>        
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" Margin="603,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="589">
            <TabItem Header="Bokade">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <ListView x:Name="lvw_bokade" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="335" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="561">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button Content="Ny plats" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Avbokade">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,1,0,-1"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Avregistrerade" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_instruktor" Content="Instruktör: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1009,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your user control?

Comment: If you mean XAML, yes, I have applied it.

Comment: Do you need it to update live?

Comment: Tzah Mama: If possible, yes but it is not high priority according to the requirement specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to update the items automatically you'll have to use some sort of a timer.
I used `DispatcherTimer` set globally in the `UserControl`

```
public DispatcherTimer dispatcher;
```

On Loaded / Ctor

```
dispatcher = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcher.Tick += CheckTime;
dispatcher.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); //Change the interval to whatever suits you best
dispatcher.Start();
```

and the method to check your data:

```
private void CheckTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbitem;
    foreach (var item in lvw_aktivitet.Items)
    {
        if ((item as Aktivitet_data).Tid > DateTime.Now)
        {
            lbitem = (ListBoxItem)lvw_aktivitet.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            lbitem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have question for you. If you need to update with the latest data. Would this  sourcecode above to be the solution? If yes, then you have to make a lot of request from the database?